# Dynamically creation of controls in asp.net c#

Tags: c#, asp.net, controls, panel, dynamic-data

I have 10 `asp:Panel`'s that include a fieldset with `asp:labels` and `asp:textboxes` in order to retrieve the data of contact details for a company. I would like to add and delete panels(contact details fieldset) and I have followed the following approach to solve my problem.

At the beginning I have these 10 panels, and only 1 panel is Visible, the remaining 9 are InVisible. When the user desires to add a new contact the following panel changes to `Visible = true`. Same approach is followed for the deletion of this particular panel(contact details fieldset), I put the particular `panel.Visible = false` and all its fields clear.

Since the company is able to retrieve for maximum 10 contacts (their details - translate to 10 panels), my problem arises when the user desires after a while to add a new panel after deletion.

For example, the user adds `Panel 1` - `Panel 2` - `Panel 3` for three contacts. Then he deletes `Panel 1` and thereafter he desires to add another Panel. Then my program finds how many panels are available yet `(visible= false)` in order to create the next Panel ( since max Panels = 10), however based on the above scenario my program creates `Panel 1` again at the same position like the page load ( to wit above `Panel 2`), but if `Panel 4` is the following available will create it down of `Panel 3` and this causes confusion to the user. The new Panel is created above or down of the last Panel depending on the rest of available panels (if the number of following panel is smaller or bigger of the last).

How can I fix my problem or am I following a completely wrong approach? I tried to use JavaScript to add new controls but I found many difficulties to recognize the IDs of each controller in order to store the data to my Database.

Comment: Why don't you post your code? Post it please to make it more readable =)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Instead of creating panel in the ASPX page you may create your panels and other controls in the code behind and then you can add them on the page from code. *(This way you may add more than 10 panels if required)*

In Code behind.

```
Panel panel1 = new Panel();
panel1.Controls.Add(yourLabel); // add your dynamically created controls
this.Page.Controls.Add(panel1); // add the panel to your page
```

Or you can create a user control with panel and other controls, load the control from the code and add them on the page. For user control you may look at the following resources.

[ASP.NET User Controls - MSDN](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/y6wb1a0e%28v=vs.100%29.aspx)
[User controls in ASP .NET - CodeProject](http://www.codeproject.com/Articles/1739/User-controls-in-ASP-NET)

Comment: since I have css and validation rules on my Panel in aspx file, can I do all of these from code behind ? what do you mean by user control ?

Comment: @mike, then the best option is user Control, you may look into the links I have provided about the user control

Answer (score 0):

You should consider using the `Repeater` control:

```
<asp:Repeater ID="rpt" runat="server">
    <ItemTemplate>
        <asp:Panel ID="pnl" runat="server">
            <%-- Code for databinding in here --%>
        </asp:Panel>
    </ItemTemplate>
</asp:Repeater>
```

Then you can use the an List inside the codebehind to represent the data inside the the repeater. Deleting and adding new lines would result in adding entries to this list. Then you can use DataBinding to present your data:

```
public void BindData(object source)
{
    rpt.DataSource = source;
    rpt.DataBind();
}
```

In the events handling adding and deleting use this code, to refresh the repeater control:

```
list.Add(...);

BindData(list);
```